# increment input field but do not change quantity already entered

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to change the input field from a 0 to a 1 if there is nothing in the field, but if someone enters 1 to 99 not default it back to 1. I'm not sure how to achieve this. Here is a js fiddle to show what I already have that does at least increment the input field to a 1 if you have a 0 when pressed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

REF: https://jsfiddle.net/oxq0vawL/3/

```js
var timesClicked = 0;

 function btnClick(){
    timesClicked ++;
     
    document.getElementById('timesClicked').value = timesClicked;
    return true 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="timesClicked" value="0">
<button name="Submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-rounded btn-outline-primary" onclick="javascript:btnClick()">Add to Cart</button>
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include my sample, thank you for the reply.

Comment: If I've understood the question, you want to replace `0` with `1` on load, unless the user entered a value other than `1`, is that right? If so, how is the default value added to the field? What if the user enters a `0`? Should that be changed to `1`, and if so how can you tell the difference between a default `0` and a user entered `0`?

Comment: Lets say I have a list of input fields on a page with multiple add to cart buttons. but if you press the add to cart button it will only change the first qty field from a **0** to a **1**, so I have an issues with the other buttons seeing the field, probably something to do with using an id I think? What I was trying to figure out was how to prevent resetting a user entered value of say **10** back to a **1**. And maybe my idea is not a feasible one and I should just remove the qty field to prevent a usability issues. Thanks